# PTIJ: What is this secret bush?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In the musaf amidah ashkenazim say:

> נַעֲרִיצְךָ וְנַקְדִישְׁךָ כְּסוד שיחַ
>
> We praise and exhalt you like a secret bush

What is this secret bush? Is it possible the authors of this line were crypto-Ugarites and were referring to an Asherah tree that they secretly kept in their basements?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a *machloket*.  Some say that it refers to the bush that Moshe saw, an insignificant thornbush in an out-of-the-way location that nonetheless led to our redemption from Mitzrayim.  Thus the bush that Hashem sent is worthy of praise.  Others say that it refers to the bush that Avraham found on Mount Moriah, the one that held the ram that was placed there at creation awaiting its purpose.  The ram was needed for Avraham's offering in substitution for Yitzchak, and the bush was needed to ensure the ram's presence.  Therefore the bush is worthy of praise.